# bash script to read values inside every file and compare them

Tags: bash

I want to plot some data of a spray simulation. There is a variable called the vaporpenetrationlength, which describes the distance from the injector to the position where the mass fraction is 0.1%. The simulation created many folders for each time step. Inside those folders there is one file which contains the mass fraction and the distance. 
I want to create a script which goes through all the time step folders and search inside this one file and prints out the distance where the 0.1% were measured and in which time step it was.
I found a script, but I don't understand it because I just started to learn shell scripting.
Could someone please help me step by step in building such a script? I am interested in learning it, and therefore I want to understand ever line of the code. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Done. please check out if it does what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little script outputs `Time`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`Length`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`Mass` based on the value of the *"mass fraction"*:

```bash
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 'Time' 'Length' 'Mass'

awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t"}
    FNR == 1 { 
        n = split(FILENAME,path,"/")
        time = sprintf("%0.7f",path[n-1])
    }
    NF != 2 {next}
    0.001 <= $2 && $2 < 0.00101 { print time,$1,$2 }
' postProcessing/singleGraphVapPen/*/*
```

<sup>**remark:** In fact, printing the header could be done within the `awk` program, but doing it with a separate `printf` command allows you to post-process the output of `awk` (for ex. if you need to sort the times and/or lengths and/or masses).</sup>

**notes:**

- `FNR == 1` is true for the first line of each input file. In the corresponding block, I extract the `time` value from the directory name.
- `NF != 2 {next}` is for filtering out the `gnuplot` commands that are at the beginning of the input files. In words, this statement means *"if the number of (tab-delimited) fields in the line isn't `2`, then skip"*
- `0.001 <= $2 && $2 < 0.00101` selects the lines based on the value of their second field, which is referred to as `yheptane` in your script. IDK the margin of error of your *"0.1% of mass fraction"* so I chose convenient conditions for the sample output below.

With the sample data, the output will be:

```
Time    Length  Mass
0.0001500   0.0895768   0.00100839
0.0002000   0.102057    0.00100301
0.0002000   0.0877939   0.00100832
0.0003500   0.0827694   0.00100114
0.0009000   0.0657509   0.00100015
0.0015000   0.0501911   0.00100016
0.0016500   0.0469495   0.00100594
0.0018000   0.0436538   0.00100853
0.0021500   0.0369005   0.00100809
0.0023000   0.100328    0.00100751
```

---

As an aside, here's a script for replacing your original code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -- postProcessing/singleGraphVapPen/*/*

if ! [ -f VapPen.txt ]
then
    {
        printf '%s\t%s\n' 'Time [s]' 'VapPen [m]'
        awk '
            BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
            FNR == 1 {
                if (NR > 1)
                    print time,vappen
                vappen = 0
                n = split(FILENAME,path,"/")
                time = sprintf("%0.7f",path[n-1])
            }
            NF != 2 {next}
            $2 >= 0.001 { vappen = $1 }
            END { if (NR) print time,vappen }
        ' "$@" |
        sort -n -k1,1
    } > VapPen.txt
fi

gnuplot -e '
    set title "Verdunstungspenetration";
    set xlabel "Zeit [s]";
    set ylabel "Verdunstungspenetrationslänge [m]";
    set grid;
    plot "VapPen.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints title "Vapor penetraion 0,1% mass";
    pause -1 "Hit return to continue";
'
```

With the provided data, it reduces the execution time from **several minutes** to **0.15s** on my computer.

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @moderators What's the point of deleting the comments that link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers/ ? How will new users know what they're supposed to do when someone answers their question?